# Blackberry Android runtime vs. NDK

Tags: android, eclipse, blackberry-playbook, blackberry-android

I'm trying to repackage an Android app for Blackberry, as suggested [here](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/android/documentation/mastertopic_1849583_11.html). The app has a native (NDK/JNI) library in it. When I try to build for the App World, I get several errors of the following kind:

```
uses-access-native:impact=5:com.myapp.MyClass
```

So on the face, it looks like NDK is not compatible with Blackberry, period. However, I could not find any official word on that. The list of known issues says that Google APIs are not supported, but not a word about NDK. What's the official line, please? Did anyone ever repackage an app with an NDK library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a note here: https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/android/apisupport

Under 'Unsupported Software Features'

•Apps that utilize native code bundled into their APK file

Comment: https://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/ -> Unsupported APIs for Gingerbread -> Software Features -> Bundled code
Apps that utilize native code bundled into their APK file.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that it's not possible to do this - as per the link paulkayuk posted, and also:

http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/bb10/porting_from_android_ndk.html

However this story popped up in the news this morning:

http://www.engadget.com/2013/02/07/skype-blackberry-android/

which references:

https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10251/is-skype-available-for-blackberry-devices?frompage=search&q=blackberry&fromSearchFirstPage=false

which says:

> If you have a new BlackBerry smartphone powered by the BlackBerry 10
>   platform, you will soon be able to download and run Skype on these
>   devices. We are working closely with BlackBerry to ensure the Skype
>   for Android app runs great in the BlackBerry 10 environment.

My understanding is that Skype on Android has a big native library accessed via NDK, so you presume for this port to have happened they are in the process of opening up a way for Android apps running on blackberry to access native code. ie. sit tight and watch this space :-)

Comment: As far as I understand that news story, it only means that BB10 has an NDK analogue of its own. It's been around since at least Playbook.

Comment: As far as I know, there's currently no NDK analogue that can be accessed from/via Android code (please correct me if I'm wrong?) - if we assume what's written on the skype website is correct, it definitely sounds like Android code on BB10 is going to be able to access native code somehow. Maybe it won't be exactly like the Android NDK, but /any/ method of interfacing a native library with ported Android Java would be a big help for quite a few apps.

Comment: The native SDK for Blackberry is [right there](https://developer.blackberry.com/ndk). And Skype, judging by the news, won't be "Android code" - it's a port. As in, a rewrite.